# How to connect mysql workbench on localhost:800

Tags: mysql, workbench

I have two local servers in my windows 8.1 , AppServer And wampServer , the Appserver is normally accessible by typing  localhost in the browser. The wamp server is accessible by localhost:800 . so i have two databases , one from Appserver ,  and the other from wamp .

Now i have MySQL workbench , and i want to connect to the wampserver database , but when attempting to connect using hostname : localhost , it shows me just the appServer database . there is any solution to use localhost:800 ?

Answer (score 0):

`localhost:800` is the port for `http` not for `mysql`.

If you have two `mysql` server then there will be two different `mysql` connector port. As you are saying one is connecting another one is not connecting. So make sure you are using correct `mysql` port.

Comment: the default mysql port is 3306 . here the situation : 
-i can access wampserver database by : localhost:800/phpmyadmin .
how can i do that in workbench ?

Comment: @user3652757.. as I have already explain to you 800 is http port not mysql, find correct mysql port in my.ini file

Comment: the same port , 3306 .